# On stacks and queue

Tags: python, stack

I have to write a program according to the following description.

> The laughs parking garage contains a single lane that hold up to ten cars. Cars arrive at the south end of the garage and leave from the north end. If a customer arrives to pick up a car that is not northernmost, all the cars to the north of his car are moved out, his car is driven out, and the others cars are restored in the same order that they were in originally. Whenever a car leaves, all the cars to the south are moved forward. So that at all the times all the empty spaces are in the south part of the garage.
>
> Write a python program to reads a group of input lines. Each line contains an “a” arrival or a “d” departure and a license plate number. Cars are assumed to arrive and depart in the order specified by the input. The program should print a message each time that a car arrives or departs. When a car arrives, the massage should specify whether or not there is room for the car in garage. If there is no room for a car, the car waits until there is room or until a departure line is read for the car. When room becomes available, another massage should be printed. When a car departs, the massage should include the number of times the car was moved within the garage (including the departure itself but not the arrival), this number is 0 if the car departs from the waiting line.

Can anybody please tell me where to start with......It should be done using stacks and queues. If you can submit a code that would be even great

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Can you kindly tell me where to begin with??? That will be really helpful... I couldn't figure out a way to break in to this question..

Comment: For the Stacks and Queues, you can use Collections.deque.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, I'd read up on what stacks and queues are: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type) and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)

Then I'd read up on Python's list types: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists. There the tutorial talks about using lists as stacks and queues (and refers to the `collections` module for the deque, which is a good queue implementation.